# Unable to see the data coming into MySQL from R

Tags: mysql, r

I am currently running a script that stores the data into MySQL using R.

```
mydb = dbConnect(MySQL(), user='root', password='xxxxxxx', dbname='test', host='localhost')

dbListTables(mydb)

dbWriteTable(mydb, name='Tables', value=parseTweets(filterStream(file.name= "", track=c("nature"), timeout=0, oauth=my_oauth)))
```

While the script is running. I would like to also analyze the data as it is coming in. When I open mySQL workbench, I do not see any data stored in the workbench.

Comment: Do you ever see it, say at the end?

Comment: If I run a code for suppose 10 second then I do see it at the end of 10 seconds.

Comment: The transaction is not settled yet (the trans can be 1 statement that takes a while). No different that without R

Comment: I also ran the above code for last 3 days but I got nothing on MySQL

Comment: So for 3 days that one above worked now it is not? And when it was working it took how long?

Comment: The code is working fine. I want to see the tweets in the MySQL, which I am unable to see with the above code. So I tried to see if it is because of the time issue. So, I set the timeout as 30 min. Even then I do not see the tweets coming into MySQL